# How to send a certificate when connecting a TCP server using SecureStreamSocket with poco

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, tcp, poco

I would like to install a TCP over SSL connection between two computers.
I'm using poco librairies in version 1.7.3.

I'm succeeded in TCP communication and verification of the server certificate on client side.

I would like to verify client certificate on server side.

Here is my **client side** connection

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler> keyHandler = new Poco::Net::KeyFileHandler(false);
SharedPtr<InvalidCertificateHandler> invalidCertHandler = new Poco::Net::ConsoleCertificateHandler(true);

// get parameters from configuration file
unsigned short port = (unsigned short) config().getInt("tcpClient.port", 9443);

Context::Ptr pClientContext = new Context(
                    Context::CLIENT_USE,
                    Application::instance().config().getString("openSSL.client.privateKeyFile"),
                    Application::instance().config().getString("openSSL.client.certificateFile"),
                    Application::instance().config().getString("openSSL.client.caConfig"),
                    Context::VERIFY_RELAXED,
                    9,
                    true,
                    Application::instance().config().getString("openSSL.client.cipherList"));

pClientContext->enableSessionCache(true);

SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(keyHandler, invalidCertHandler, pClientContext);

Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("127.0.0.1", port);
SecureStreamSocket ss1(sa, pClientContext);

app.logger().information("Client connecté");
```

Here is my **server side** listen connection

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
// get parameters from configuration file
unsigned short port = (unsigned short) config().getInt("tcpServer.port", 9443);

// set-up a server socket
SecureServerSocket svs(port);
Poco::Net::TCPServer srv(new EchoServerConnectionFactory(), svs);
// start the Server
srv.start();
logger().information("Attente de connexion client ...");
```

And the **createConnection** method of my EchoServerConnectionFactory

```
Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection* createConnection(const Poco::Net::StreamSocket& socket)
    {
        Application& app = Application::instance();

        app.logger().information("Tentative de connexion d'un client");

        if (!socket.secure())
        {
            app.logger().error("Client non sécurisé. Connexion refusée");
            return NULL;
        }

        try
        {
            Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket securedSocket = (Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket)dynamic_cast<const Poco::Net::StreamSocket&>(socket);

            if (!securedSocket.havePeerCertificate())
            {
                app.logger().error("Le client n'a pas présenté de certificat. Connexion refusée");
                return NULL;
            }
         ....
         ....
```

In the **createConnection** method, the method **securedSocket.havePeerCertificate() always returns false**. I must have missed something in secureSocket initialization client side but I don't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a method to make it work.

I've add following line

```
securedSocket.completeHandshake();
```

before checking client certificate on server code.

Final code :

```
Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket securedSocket = (Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket)dynamic_cast<const Poco::Net::StreamSocket&>(socket);

securedSocket.completeHandshake();
if (!securedSocket.havePeerCertificate())
{
     .....
     .....
```

The method **securedSocket.havePeerCertificate()** now succeed.

But I'm not sure I'm making the correct workflow to validate SSL communication. Any other way ?